# Java - how to access a class in another running application

Tags: java, sockets

In my scenario, I have a server running which waits for a client to make a connection.  It is necessary for a client to instantiate the connection because the computer I'm looking to communicate with has more restrictive network security than I do.  The client will connect to me daily.  So I have a jar file and process running that handles this.  Server side on my end, and client side on the other end.  Next, I have a web page running, and when a user clicks a specific button, I need to tell the Server app, "okay, now send data to the client".

What is the best way to accomplish this?  First of all, is there a problem with the client waiting around for data?  Do I need anything special here like heartbeats etc? Is it possible to reverse the scenario and have a server connect to a client instead?

Next, how can I make it so that the application I launch when the user clicks a button actually talks to an already running jar which is handling the connection?

Comment: So many questions in single post. I think it is better to post different questions for different issues.

Comment: if the server and client are on the same machine, just use sockets and implement a shared protocol, otherwise look into RMI (and maybe even web services).

Comment: The client and server are on different machines, however the server and the application that is triggered when the user clicks a button are on the same machine.  I will look into RMI

Comment: @Marianna, "*however the server and the application that is triggered when the user clicks a button are on the same machine*"..then don't use RMI..use sockets.

Comment: Why do you say that?  I'm using sockets already for the Client/Server setup.  I suppose I could do something like 1) Server waits for client  2) Server waits for local connection 3) Server receives local data 4) Server passes local data to client.  Something like that.  Only trick is I need to differentiate between the two connections somehow.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is decide the transport layer. If you use [RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) -which makes sense if you use Java in all the endpoints of comunication- you don't need the heatbeat or something.

I should define, in web-app context (are you using Spring?) a unique instance that initializes an RMI object and publishes it at RMI registry, so clients can connect to it.

As this object is created inside webapp process (and webapp classloader), it has access to some queue object you use. Then your webapp can add items to that queue.

Your RMI object should have to execute in a separate thread (don't create indiscriminate threads in Java EE, just one! or use some framework as Quartz) and consume from the blocking queue.

```
[webapp]
   configfile
   create thread with server object
      publish server object with getinfo method
      getinfo method consumes from queue (queue.take())


[client]
    connect via RMI to server object
    call method get info
```

If a client can stay a lot without reading a new item, and there are a LOT of clients, maybe it's worth to return null from the queue where there are no items (or it timeouts).

Comment: There is only one client, and no I am not using Spring or anything fancy.  The clicking of the button literally calls "java -jar myJar.jar" which I want to run some calculation, and then pass data to the already running Server, which then passes it to the client who waits all day on an external machine.  Can I use RMI to expose a method in the server JVM that passes it to the client when received?

Comment: Yes, RMI is for calling methods on remote objects. Remote meaning an object on any other JVM. You only have to "register" that object programatically in some RMI registry. The client can obtain a reference an send info.

Comment: I've mentioned Spring just for the initialization. If you have a simple webapp you can define a Context Listener in web.xml and that listener, onContextInitialized (it is, on webapp start) can create the necesary object, add it to webapp context for accessing it from webapp and registering in the RMI registry for accessing from any other remote caller. If you want I can add sample code later...

Answer (score 0):

Client-Server communications can be easily achieved via a RESTful web service. And communications between applications on the same local machine can be easily achieved using sockets and a common communications protocol.